# How to set pointer position on screen

Tags: c#, winforms, hook

I'm learning using Window Hook with examples on Code Project. I have got position of pointer on screen, but can't find the way of setting position pointer again. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the `Cursor.Position` property.